# Frictional torque=?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, work, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

A uniform, hollow, cylindrical spool has inside radius
$R/2$, outside radius $ R$, and mass $M $ (see figure below). It is
mounted so that it rotates on a mass less horizontal axle.
A mass m is connected to the end of a string wound
around the spool. The mass $m$ falls from rest through a
distance $y$ in time $t$. Show that the torque due to the
frictional forces between spool and axle is

> $\tau_{f} = R[m(g - 2y/t^ 2)-  M(5y/4t^ 2)]$

[image: Fig.]

I am getting a somewhat near answer but not exactly same (in my answer few terms are missing).

What I did is,  Net Torque $(mgR-\tau_f) = I\alpha$  (and  $ \alpha = a/R$, $I=\frac{M}{2}(R^2+(\frac{R}{2})^2$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential energy change of mass $m$ is equal to kinetic energy change of system ($m$ and $M$) plus wasted energy due to friction between spool and axle.
$$mgy=\frac 12mv^2+\frac 12I\omega^2+W_f\tag 1$$
$\omega=\large{\frac{v^2}R}$

As the tension force of the string is constant, then the net force acting on mass $m$ will be constant ($F_{\textrm{net}}=mg-T$). Hence, acceleration of the mass $m$ will be constant. So, we will have:
$$v=\large{\frac{2y}t}$$
On the other hand,
$$W_f=\tau_f\theta$$
$\theta=\large{\frac yR}\;\Longrightarrow\;W_f=\large{\frac yR}\tau_f$

By substituting known amounts in equation ($1$), the given answer will be obtained.

Comment: i dont get v= 2y/t?

Comment: $y=\frac 12at^2$ and $v=at$ then $v=\frac {2y}t$

Comment: oh gr8, can u point out ma mistake too plz, thnx!

Comment: The torque acting on spool isn't $mgR-\tau_f$

Comment: Forces that exert torque on the spool are 1.friction force between spool and axle and 2. friction force between string and spool. There is no $mg$ in play.

Comment: k, u mean it shud be tension instead of mg

Comment: Not completely. Because tension force of the string doesn't act on the spool. This is rather complex to find friction force between string and spool.

Comment: k, got it thnx again